# UITableview inside Scrollview call cellforrow too many times

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview inside a scrollview, and I have 1000 rows.
Then app call cellForRowAtIndexPath 1000 times, even there are not all visible in device. It make my app really slow.

So how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // tableView.tag >= 80000 為popTable
    if tableView.tag < k79995 {
        var cell: BookmarkContentCell!
        if indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row < channelArray.count - 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: middleReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookmarkContentCell
        } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: firstReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookmarkContentCell
            cell.cellPosition = .first
        } else if indexPath.row == channelArray.count - 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: lastReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BookmarkContentCell
        }
        cell.musicTitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.musicTitleLabel.text = channelArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.musicTitleLabel.textColor = FONT_COLOR_2
        cell.moreBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.moreBtn.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
        cell.moreBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreBtnPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let imageURL = channelArray[indexPath.row].thumbnailURL

        cell.loadCoverImage(imageURL: imageURL)

        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        addCellBackground(cell, row: indexPath.row, count: channelArray.count)
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2, bottom: 0, right: 2)
        cell.coverImageView.isOpaque = true
        cell.moreBtn.isOpaque = true
        cell.musicTitleLabel.isOpaque = true
        counter += 1
        DLog("cellforrow::indexPath.row:: \(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    } else {    // 彈出對話框
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: POP_TABLE_VIEW_CELL_IDENTIFY)
        if cell == nil {
            let nib = UINib(nibName: POP_TABLE_VIEW_CELL_XIB_NAME, bundle: nil)
            tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: POP_TABLE_VIEW_CELL_IDENTIFY)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: POP_TABLE_VIEW_CELL_IDENTIFY)
        }
        cell!.textLabel?.text = popBoxTitles[indexPath.row]
        cell!.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2, bottom: 0, right: 2)
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code of your `cellForRow`

Comment: @Tj3n already update~

Comment: You are using same type of cell, why you need to `dequeueReusableCell ` so many times? Just use one. Also the `tableView.register` should be called one time only, put it in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Also using `tag` is bad practice, use delegate pattern instead

Comment: Is `cell.loadCoverImage()` asynchronous ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes.....

Answer (score 0):

It's my stupid。The belowing code cause the problem.

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```