# UIScrollView not scrolling with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am trying to implement a scrollView that contains a text field, button, and table view. I am completely lost trying to get the thing to scroll, I've tried changing the height of UITableView but that has not worked, I've tried adjusting the height of the content View and scrollView, but that has not worked either. How can I get the scrollview to scroll and adjust the size when another tableViewCell is added to the tableView?

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) * 120))
        tableView.reloadData()

    }


@IBAction func addExercisePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    test.append("nice")
    tableView.reloadData()
    
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x,y: tableView.frame.origin.y ,width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(test.count * 120))
    scrollView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height)
    
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why tableview inside a scrollview? You can use a single tableview to achieved same layout without any problem you mention

Comment: How so, I want buttons to scroll with the view, is that possible in a tableView?

Comment: Use tableheaderview

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: after further review, tableheaderview cannot accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: table headerview does not scroll with the tableview cells, which is what I'm trying to accomplish with a tableView(scroll disabled), button, and dynamic textView all inside a scrollView

Comment: tableHeaderView is scrollable, sectionHeaderView is sticky, please recheck again

Answer (score 1):

Please dont use tableView inside a scrollView, tableView is subclass of scrollView and that's mean tableView already have scroll function

your answer to set

```
tableHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```

It will make recycle/dequeue cell function useless because tableView will show all the cell immediately, tableview will call cellForRowAt for all indexes that showed in tableview viewport

[UITableview inside Scrollview call cellforrow too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994044/uitableview-inside-scrollview-call-cellforrow-too-many-times)

Here why we use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e)

From what I see you want something like this right

[image]

you can check this [repo](https://github.com/aiwiguna/TestTableHeader) how I only use **a tableview** to achieved that

please note that tableHeaderView is scrollable, sectionHeaderView is sticky

Comment: ```tableHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height``` is only called when another cell is added, it is not called in CellForRow

Comment: it will make cellForRow called for every cell in your tableView, andmake dequeueCell not working as intended

Comment: you can watch this explanation about tableView recycle cell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2y7oljRacg

Comment: @Noah Iarrobino try show very large amount of cell (ex: 100000000) and you will see the problem

Comment: @NoahIarrobino it will make your app use more memory and might make UI/UX glitch in some case, that number is just for an easy example, but if you don't care about that, it's up to you. Even Apple say "You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled."

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to set a height constraint for the TableView and connect that via IBOutlet, then this line of code wherever reloading table data is needed

```
tableHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: this will make a memory problem because it will make recycle function useless https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994044/uitableview-inside-scrollview-call-cellforrow-too-many-times